# insert image with relative path in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to insert an image in angular2.
My picture name is saved in `mypicture` variable.
I tried in this way `<img [src]="../../../public/img/{{mypicture}}" />` but it didn't work.

I see this error in the console:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
```

Comment: `<img [src]="'../../../public/img/' + mypicture" />` does not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of doing that 
contact the full path before binding

for example:

```
public fullPath:string;
public myPicture:string;

getMyPicture(){
   this.fullPath = "../../../public/img/"+ this.myPicture;
 }
```

html

```
 <img [src]="fullPath" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need a mix of " and '.

```
<img [src]="'../../../public/img/' + mypicture" />
```

That's it.
Quick and easy fix.

Answer (score 2):

Property binding allows you to bind the property to an expression. You can read about template expression here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions

Generally speaking, what you can put on the right hand side is what you put in your curly braces for interpolation, so {{expression}}, you cannot use interpolation in this case. So you would need to have the path to your image in your component's property and then you just bind the [src] to your property directly. Like:

```
<img [src]="propertyWithPathFromComponent" />
```

Just in case you would still interpolate the string this way, you can go for:

```
<img src="{{pathToYourImage}}" />
```